# Why is session data empty in Symfony2 and how to access it?

Tags: php, session, symfony

A third-party PHP application stores data in the user's session (using a cookie for PHPSESSID). In this app, the `$_SESSION` variable contains all this data.

In my Symfony2 application, the same `$_SESSION` only contains some Symfony data (`_sf2_attributes`, `_security_secured_area`, `_sf2_flashes`, etc.) and I don't see any other data from the other app.

I did a `var_dump` of the $_SESSION variable in a controller to check this. Using the Symfony Session object shows the same data.
The 2 apps use the same domain for storing the PHPSESSID cookie.

How can I get all data of the session in my Symfony app? I would like the session to be shared between the 2 applications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.
Symfony stores its session data in its own directory (`app/cache/[environment]/sessions`). So the solution is to set the default session path in `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path: ~
```

This will set the default path back (for example `/var/lib/php5` on Linux) and the legacy app session data is made available to the Symfony app.