# Symfony2, symfony1.4 and $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, symfony-1.4, session-variables, symfony-2.1

I have a project where I want to use `Symfony2.1` and `symfony 1.4` and of course I need to share some data between them with the session, but I don't understand why the sessions are not visible between them.
For example:

In a symfony1 filter I have:

```
echo session_id().'<br>';
echo session_name();
$_SESSION['test_s1'] = '123';
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

and the result is:

```
d30irfcdhjio27uiqd7a52blv7
symfony
array (size=6)
  'symfony/user/sfUser/lastRequest' => int 1356289903
  'symfony/user/sfUser/authenticated' => boolean false
  'symfony/user/sfUser/credentials' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'symfony/user/sfUser/attributes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'symfony/user/sfUser/culture' => string 'en_US' (length=5)
  'test_s1' => string '123' (length=3)
```

So, everything looks fine.

In a Symfony2 controller I have:

```
echo session_id() . '<br>';
echo session_name();
$_SESSION['test_s2'] = '123';
$session->set('test_s2_second', '321');
var_dump($_SESSION);
die;
```

And the result:

```
d30irfcdhjio27uiqd7a52blv7
symfony
array (size=4)
  '_sf2_attributes' => &
    array (size=4)
      'razvan' => string 'test' (length=4)
      '_security_secured_area' => string 'C:74:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":777:{a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;s:12:"secured_area";i:2;s:728:"a:4:{i:0;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User":7:{s:51:"?Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User?username";s:6:"user";s:51:"?Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User?password";s:8:"userpass";s:50:"?Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User?enabled";b:1;s:60:"?Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User?accountNonExpired";b:1;s:64:"?Symfony\Component\Security\Core'... (length=865)
      'search_form' => string '' (length=0)
      'test_s2_second' => string '321' (length=3)
  '_sf2_flashes' => &
    array (size=0)
      empty
  '_sf2_meta' => &
    array (size=3)
      'u' => int 1356289889
      'c' => int 1356287606
      'l' => string '0' (length=1)
  'test_s2' => string '123' (length=3)
```

So, the session_id and session_name are the same, but I cannot see the session's keys/values I set through symfony1 in Symfony2 and also the other way around even if I use the $_SESSION.

The architecture behind is more complex and I tried to expose only the main problem.

So, any idea how can I set some variables into session from Symfony2.1 and to be visible in symfony 1.4 pages ?

(I did the same trick with Symfony2.0 and the trick worked).

Comment: Isn't it the same problem the was solved with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12710798/1229023)?

Comment: yes. it seems this was the problem. tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is session data empty in Symfony2 and how to access it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705048/why-is-session-data-empty-in-symfony2-and-how-to-access-it)

Answer (score 0):

There is a cookbook article about the topic in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/php_bridge.html). Here is a blog post by theodo (their profile is to port symfony1 applications to Symfony2) about [how to share the sessions using memcache](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/06/sharing-session-between-symfony1-and-symfony2-using-memcache-2/) and they have a [bundle (TheodoEvolutionSessionBundle)](https://github.com/theodo/TheodoEvolutionSessionBundle) as well. And there is also a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZocRPreQ5g) about this and other problems of porting legacy applications to Symfony2.